# Product Classification loading image error in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, image-processing, google-colaboratory

Recently i was doing a product classification project, i have a pre-classified dataset 'train' with 41 folders corresponding to each category of products, and its csv file listing the image name and its category.

Then, i have another 'test' dataset with bunch of unclassified products, the project wished to classfied those pictures and output a csv file with "name" and "category"

I was using google colab in this project, after i successfully load and mount all the files and i ready to scan the trained image, i got an error about it, below is my code

```
train_image = []

for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):

    img = image.load_img('content/train/train/'+train[i].astype('str')+'.jpg', target_size=(28,28,1))

    img = image.img_to_array(img)

    img = img/255

    train_image.append(img)

X = np.array(train_image)
```

and this is the error i get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

This is how the my training directory looks like in google colab

```
--content
  ↳train  
    ↳train  
      ↳0  
      ↳1  
      ....  
      ↳41
```

What to do to eliminated that error?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that recommendations for external resources (tutorials etc) is [strictly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here (edited question to remove it).

Comment: @desertnaut Oh okk thanks for the reminder i was really new here

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get it it's the format problem of load_image

```
img = image.load_img(r'train/train/' + str(train_df['category'][i]) + '/' + train_df['filename'][i], target_size=(28,28))
```